# HTML style for <label> and <del> identical but giving different results

Tags: html, css

I have been building a to-do list style app in asp.net and been using the label tag for text and the del tag for crossed out text (when an item is done but not yet deleted)

i have been trying to add a simple style inline to help with the spacing and want them to produce identical results.

```
<label style="Width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The Unfinished item</label>

<del style="Width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The crossed out item</del>
```

this should wrap the text for anything greater than 330px but keep the space for itself when it is shorter than that. the label works perfectly however the del doesn't seem to do any of it.

is it not possible to style a del tag or have i missed something obvious?

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps add a 'display:inline-block;'? https://jsfiddle.net/j2g8aknz/

Comment: From the prose I assume you meant `min-width` rather than `max-width`. Aside from that however, there shouldn't be any difference in behaviour for `label` and `del`, apart from the line-through. Better check the rest of your CSS for other styles assigned to one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an display:inline-block; so you actually use your 'width'.

```html
<label style="display:inline-block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The Unfinished item The Unfinished item The Unfinished item </label>
<br>
<del style="display:inline-block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The crossed out item The crossed out item The crossed out item </del>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can remove the `max-width: 330px;` rule. It's redundant.

If you don't want the `del` tag to break the line, use the rule `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `display`: `block` | `inline-block` | `inherit`. The value you can adjust to the needs.

Example with `display: block;`

```html
<label style="display:block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The Unfinished item The Unfinished item The Unfinished item </label>
<br>
<del style="display:block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The crossed out item The crossed out item The crossed out item </del>
```

Example with `display: inline-block;`

```html
<label style="display:inline-block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The Unfinished item The Unfinished item The Unfinished item </label>
<br>
<del style="display:inline-block; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The crossed out item The crossed out item The crossed out item </del>
```

Example with `display: inherit;`

```html
<label style="display:inherit; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The Unfinished item The Unfinished item The Unfinished item </label>
<br>
<del style="display:inherit; width: 330px; max-width: 330px; word-wrap: break-word">The crossed out item The crossed out item The crossed out item </del>
```